# How to IMPORT passwords to Google Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, password, import, export

I would like to import my passwords from ***Chrome*** for **Windows** to ***Chrome*** for **Android** and because I do not sync any data via google account and I do not want to, how do I manage to do that. I've tried enabling the flag in **"chrome://flags"** but it only shows the **"Export"** button. If someone knows a way to fix/do that I would be very happy!
Thank you!

Comment: Related: [Google Chrome Help - Cannot import passwords when using Chrome for Android](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10226261/cannot-import-passwords-when-using-chrome-for-android)